# what is the command+k ( in mac ) equivalent in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal

I am used to `command + k` to clear up the terminal in mac. It is very helpful specially while debugging through server logs. What is the equivalent in Ubuntu system ?

Comment: FYI - apparently this is called "clear scrollback" or "clearing the scrollback buffer" and is a function of the terminal program (not the shell, such as bash or zsh).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Clearing the screen**

This will work for both Mac OS X and *nix:

`Ctrl-l`

My answer assumes the default terminal emulators for bash, tcsh (default for Mac OS X) or zsh.

**Deleting the scrollback buffer (more like ⌘K)**

This has been asked/answered [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036829/clear-scrollback-buffer-of-linux-virtual-console-terminals).

Comment: can you post please your Terminal.app preferences, and/or something to show HOW you enabled CTRL-L for the clear in the OS X Terminal.app? (Because in my Mac CTRL-L does not works).

Comment: It's a bash, tcsh and zsh supported short-cut. It's got nothing to do with Terminal.app

Comment: Strange, because it's does not clear for me. I'm using bash --version: GNU bash, version 4.2.0(1)-release (i386-apple-darwin10.7.0)

Comment: Just found the problem source. You must have "set -o emacs" for CTRL-L, (what is default), but i'm using vi-mode. :)

Comment: What if you go into Terminal -> Preferences -> Settings -> Keyboard and tick "Use option as meta key"?

Comment: Ah, ok :-) Glad you got it working.

Comment: On my Mac, `Control + l` inserts a bunch of space below the last output so that the screen appears clear, but you can still scroll up and see the previous output. `Command + K`, on the other hand, makes it impossible to scroll back to the previous output. Sometimes that is preferable. Do you know how to do the latter on other Unix systems? (Also I don't think bash or zsh are relevant so much as the terminal emulator.)

Answer (score 2):

^L - the equivalent to 'clear' command

I guess this is what you were searching for

Comment: I was searching for a shortcut for clearing up the screen so that whatever comes next will be visible clearly because I don't want to see the previous texts. I use command+K in mac , i set shortcut for clear and reset in ubuntu , that sortof worked for me though.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a key chord, but if you want to clear your terminal and  *recover* it if it gets hosed, you can use the 'reset' command. I know this works in linux and BSD, not sure about OSX.

Comment: reset works in OSX as well .